# What does static and IOException mean?

Tags: java

I just had a test on java and we had to give the definition of
1) Static:
2) IOExcepion:

What I said for static was...a static method is used to define a method as a class method. And I got it wrong so I asked my teacher and he said he wants the actually definition of static not a static method, class or variable just static. Can someone tell me the definition of this and for IOException please Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Static - A member/method that belongs to a class, not an instance of a class (Does not need to be instaciated to be used).

IOException - Exception thrown when there has been an Input/Output (usually when working with files) error.

Comment: Does that definition of `static` apply to nested `static class` as well?

Comment: @Jorn, in a sense, yes. But it is the outer class that does not have to be instantiated for the nested class to be used. That is consistent, if you squint just the right way.

Comment: @ThatBlairGuy, not true.  When speaking nested static classes, you instantiate it by calling: OuterClass.StaticNestedClass nestedObject = new OuterClass.StaticNestedClass();

Comment: when you use __static class__ you are not telling that the class is static (since an outside class decl is static by definition), but you are telling that the nested declaration of the class is static. So we're talking about the declaration, not the class itself..

Comment: Gah, got my languages confused again.  Different languages, different nuances.  I've deleted the comment.

Answer (score 1):

[IOException](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html)

> Signals that an I/O exception of some
>   sort has occurred. This class is the
>   general class of exceptions produced
>   by failed or interrupted I/O
>   operations.

[Static keyword](http://java.sun.com/docs/glossary.html#S)

> A Java keyword used to define a
>   variable as a class variable. Classes
>   maintain one copy of class variables
>   regardless of how many instances exist
>   of that class. static can also be used
>   to define a method as a class method.
>   Class methods are invoked by the class
>   instead of a specific instance, and
>   can only operate on class variables.

Answer (score 1):

*Static* methods, fields, and nested classes are all associated with a Class, rather than an instance of that Class.  From the Java tutorial:

> the static keyword [is used] to create
>   fields and methods that belong to the
>   class, rather than to an instance of
>   the class.

So, nested classes marked as static can be instantiated without an instance of the containing class.  Because nested static classes are decoupled with the containing class, they do not have access to other members of the containing class.

Similarly, static methods can be called by referring to `ClassName.method()`, and static variables by `ClassName.variable`.

*IOException*: A checked exception thrown when working with input/output operations (e.g. when dealing with files or sockets.)

Answer (score 1):

the `static` keyword is used on `variables` or `methods` (even `classes)`to tell that they are associated with a `class` definition and not with an instance (of the class).

This means that every object of a class will share the same `static` fields/methods because they are associated with the definition itself. Moreover you won't need any instance to refer to this field/methods because you can easily obtain them using the `class` itself.

The concept of `static class` is used with nested class. Since a nested class may not be static, if you need to reference it from a static context you have to explicitly declare it to be static, otherwise the declaration would be associated with an instance, without allowing you to use it from static contexts..

the `IOException` is just a subtype of `Exception` used by JDK to raise exceptions related to input/output problems. It's not a `RuntimeException`, so it's a checked one that must be caught whenever a method can throw it. This means that the exception is actually used to inform callers that something went wrong while working with I/O

Answer (score 0):

The above definitions for static are correct. As a quick example, think about if you had a "Bicycle" class. If you wanted a variable to store the number of wheels, it would make sense to be a static variable. If you created 100 Bicycle objects, there's no point in storing the number of wheels 100 times, since all Bicycles have two wheels.

Answer (score 0):

1.**Static**-The static keyword in Java means that the variable/function is shared between all instances of that perticular class as it belongs to type, not the actual objects themselves.

2.**IO Exception** - Signals that an I/O exception of some sort has occurred. This class is the general class of exceptions produced by failed or interrupted I/O operations. It is generally used in IO file.